# Why is it grammatical to say 'It's the holidays'?

Tags: verb-agreement

I have come across the following sentence in Oxford Grammar for Schools 4 by Martin Moore:

> *It's* the holidays. I don't have to get up very early.

Why isn't the subject of the sentence in agreement with the compliment? Is it correct to say '*They're* the holidays'? - I find it rather odd sounding, though.

Comment: This "it" functions as dummy subject. It's meaningless -- not a semantic argument -- and simply serves the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position. Plural complements are common, though in most cases express spatial or temporal extent, as in "It's five miles to the nearest town"; "It's only five weeks until Christmas".

Answer (score 2):

That's not any different from "It's Saturday, I'm sleeping in" or "It's the weekend, let's do something fun."

**It** there is existential as in "*It's* raining".

Comment: OK, how am I to know then when it's external and when it's not? any rule on that?

Comment: If it's not a cleft sentence or an extraposition, chances are it's an existential use.